# Creating geometry based on the transparency of a PNG image

Tags: bevel

I'm importing a PNG icon as a plane, but the problem is that the plane imports with the transparent background, making it a square plane. I don't want my plane to be a square, it should just be the PNG icon itself.

Here's an example:

[image: ImagePlane]

I'm trying to use the Bevel tool to adjust the corners of my plane, but that cannot be done if my plane is basically a square.

Is it possible to remove the transparent background completely, so that my plane is just the chess piece itself?

Thanks

Comment: Please use "edit" to insert your linked image into text of your Question directly (not as an external link) Thank you. It is for future purpose.

Comment: Only by modeling that shape manually if you dont have this icon in vector format. You can add Bezier Curve to shape it and image reuse as material texture or use mesh object to model it, or use Knife (K) tool to cut shape into plane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You can start from plane

- from bottom extruding (E) on Y axis, scale (S) and repeat process up to top.
- add Subsurface Modifier
- Sharp edge (Shift+E) = 1 (pink edges)

[image]

- Unwrap (U) > Project from View
- switch to UV Edit layout (from top row) and adjust position on image in edit mode

[image]
[image]
(if you need more smooth shape increase Modifier)

---

### You can start from Curve Object

- add Curve > Bezier
  (in edit mode select and delete all, click with Ctrl to create a new point)
- Extrude (E) selected point to shape
- change handle type (V) for corner points

[image]
[image]

From half of shape you can generate **3D object by Screw Modifier**
[image]

*Convert to Mesh* object you can use Boolean Modifier to Intersect another object to finish cut.
[image]
[image]

---

### You can use Knife tool

- go to edit mode hit (K) Knife to do cuts arround the drawing, but it is a bit dirty way, since plane is already Unwrapped moving points will move texture as well (there was an option to disable moving UV, but I cant find it now). To smooth shape in specific part you can use Subdivision Surface modifier as well, but triangulate it first.

[image]

Example all of them (Plane visible, others are hidden from Outliner)
[image]

---

### You can use Greace Pencil

- to redraw icon from scratch